# how to change "Build Host" in rpm

Tags: linux, rpm

I need to change the "Build Host" name to other that actual host-name , fqdn(picked from /etc/hosts)

During the rpm generation,We set rpm properties via .spec file, but I understand "Build Host" values can't be set via .spec file.

Is there a way to change the "Build Host" value in rpm without actually changing the hostname of linux machine.

i.e. No change in /etc/sysconfig/network 
or

https://www.onyxpoint.com/spoofing-the-build-hostname-in-mock/

Answer (score 4):

Before typing `rpmbuild -ba something.spec` I've changed the first line in `/etc/hosts`:
From :
`127.0.0.1 localhost my.local.domain.com`
To :
`127.0.0.1 'what-I-want-to-appear-on-build-host' localhost my.local.domain.com`

It worked just fine for me and I didn't change anything on the `.spec` file.

Answer (score 1):

It will be possible in Fedora 25+:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1309367

Answer (score 1):

I've done it with `LD_PRELOAD` hooking the same way your article links, but I've wrapped it in `Makefiles` that handle both 32-bit and 64-bit compilations.

[Enjoy](http://www.revragnarok.com/blog/blog/rpm_spoof_hostname).